# How can I get all the data of a Shopify store product for my app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, shopify-app

For example, I want to do an **application** to get from this URL all the data(title, images, variants, etc...): https://www.tluxe.com/products/slouch-pant-black
And after that I want to add this product to my store.
How could I do it?

Comment: do you have the authentication key? if yes, you can fetch all this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this thing:

https://www.tluxe.com/products/slouch-pant-black.json

You will get everything you want. :)
Append the URL with **.json**